# How to send value attribute from radio button in PHP

Tags: php, radio-button, send

I am struggling with sending the value of a radiobutton to an email.

I have coded 2 radiobuttons, where I have set the first on to be default checked.

The form and values work, however the radio button value is not submitted.

Any wise words?

Comment: Without your code, all we can do is copy and paste from the HTML spec.

Answer (score 22):

When you select a radio button and click on a submit button, you need to handle the submission of any selected values in your php code using `$_POST[]`
For example:
if your radio button is:

```
<input type="radio" name="rdb" value="male"/>
```

then in your php code you need to use:

```
$rdb_value = $_POST['rdb'];
```

Comment: thanks, yes it was the value attribute ... I was teaching myself from scratch, but your answer actually helped me solve several other problems too ... so thank you very much :-)

Answer (score 5):

Check whether you have put name="your_radio" where you have inserted radio tag

if you have done this then check your php code. Use isset()

e.g.

```
   if(isset($_POST['submit']))
   {
    /*other variables*/
    $radio_value = $_POST["your_radio"];
   }
```

If you have done this as well then we need to look through your codes

Comment: should I use  same name for radio buttons in html?

Comment: yes and the value will be either true or false

Answer (score 2):

The radio buttons are sent on form submit when they are checked only...

use `isset()` if true then its checked otherwise its not

Answer (score 2):

When you select a radio button and click on a submit button, you need to handle the submission of any selected values in your php code using $_POST[]
For example:
if your radio button is:

```
<input type="radio" name="rdb" value="male"/>
```

then in your php code you need to use:

```
$rdb_value = $_POST['rdb'];
```

Answer (score 2):

Radio buttons have another attribute - checked or unchecked. You need to set which button was selected by the user, so you have to write PHP code inside the HTML with these values - checked or unchecked. Here's one way to do it:

**The PHP code:**

```
<?PHP
    $male_status = 'unchecked';
    $female_status = 'unchecked';

    if (isset($_POST['Submit1'])) {
         $selected_radio = $_POST['gender'];

         if ($selected_radio == 'male') {
                $male_status = 'checked';
          }else if ($selected_radio == 'female') {
                $female_status = 'checked';
          }
    }
?>
```

**The HTML FORM code:**

```
<FORM name ="form1" method ="post" action ="radioButton.php">
   <Input type = 'Radio' Name ='gender' value= 'male'
   <?PHP print $male_status; ?>
   >Male
   <Input type = 'Radio' Name ='gender' value= 'female' 
   <?PHP print $female_status; ?>
   >Female
   <P>
   <Input type = "Submit" Name = "Submit1" VALUE = "Select a Radio Button">
</FORM>
```

Comment: There shouldn't be a space in `= =`.

Answer (score 1):

Should be :

HTML :

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <input id="name" name="name" type="text" size="40"/>
    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="test"/>Test
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

PHP Code :

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

    echo $radio_value = $_POST["radio"];
}
```