# how to return value of 0 when no radio button is selected in php

Tags: php, radio-button

I am working on online exam system in the answer sheet i have `RadioButton` I have four radio buttons for each question and i want to return the value of 0 when none of them are selected

Comment: this may hlep  - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14747803/how-to-send-radio-button-value-in-php

Comment: If none of them are selected, the radio button won't be accessible in the `POST` superglobal, you could check in php if it is set when processing otherwise mark it as `0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php echo isset($_REQUEST['this_button']) ? $_REQUEST['this_button'] : '0' ?>
```

this will set it to 0 if nothing is selected

There's also this [interesting read](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/radio-buttons-default-selection/) about whether you should have a value in a radio button preselected or not. So consider having a hidden radiobutton element whose value is 0 and is preselected

Answer (score 0):

You need to have five `RadioButtons`, one of them should have the value of 0 and should be invisible. That should be selected on default.

Comment: If this solved the problem, then you might accept the answer.