# how to get value from radio button in php

Tags: php, html, database, radio-button

I have a table and on that table I have column called Status. under status column I have two radio button side by side one is ready and another one is not ready, now I want to get any one value in each row from those radio buttons and store the value in to a database. But It is captured only the first row radio button value which ever I choose from them and then copy the value into every row and store into a database. below is the code I have..

**HTML CODE:**

```
<form action = "submit_varification.php" method = "POST" onclick = "return validate()">
                            <div style="position: absolute; left: 50px; top: 90px;">
                            <label class="right"><font color="white">Date:</font></label>
                            <input type="text" id = "frmDate"  /><br>
                            <p id="date"></p>
                            </div>
                            <div style="position: absolute; left: 250px; top: 91px;">
                            <label class="right"><font color="white">V-ID:</font></label>
                            <input type="text" id = "myText" name = "reviewer" value = ""/><br>
                            </div>
                            <div style="position: absolute; left: 900px; top: 91px;">
                            <button type="button" name="show" id="show" onclick = "" >History</button>
                            </div>
                            <div style="position: absolute; left: 900px;">
                            <input type="submit" name="test" id="test" value="Submit"  /><br/>
                            </div>

                        <script>
                        var date = new Date();

                        document.getElementById("frmDate").value = (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getDate() + '/' + date.getFullYear();

                        </script>
                    </body>
                    <table style="position: absolute; width:95%; left: 20px; top: 150px;" id = "table1">
                        <?php
                        $myDate = date('m/d/Y');
                        ?>
                            <tr>
                            <th>Date</th>
                            <th>Time</th> 
                            <th>Alias</th>
                            <th>Machine_Name</th>
                            <th>Build_Name</th>
                            <th>Build_version</th>
                            <th>WinDBG</th>
                            <th>.Net_Framework</th>
                            <th>Status</th>
                            </tr>
                            <?php
                                //get records from database
                                $sql3 = "SELECT * FROM data WHERE `Date` = '".$myDate."' ORDER BY id DESC";
                                $query = $conn->query($sql3);
                                if($query->num_rows > 0){
                                while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
                                <tr> 
                                <td><?php echo $row['Date']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['Time']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['Alias']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['Machine_Name']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['Build_Name']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['Build_Version']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['WinDBG']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['.NET_Framework']; ?></td>
                                <td style='white-space: nowrap'><form><label class = "ready"><input type="radio" name="status" value = "Ready">Ready</label><label class = "notready"><input type="radio" name="status" value = "Not Ready" >Not Ready</label></form></td>
                                </tr> 
                                <?php } } ?>

                            </table>
                            </form>
```

**PHP CODE:**

```
<?php

                            session_start();
                            $myDate = date('m/d/Y');
                            $servername = "localhost";
                            $username = "root";
                            $password = "wipro@123";
                            $dbname = "testbad_information";
                            $date = date("m/d/Y");

                            // Create connection
                            $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
                            $sql4 = "SELECT * FROM data WHERE `Date` = '".$myDate."' ORDER BY id DESC";
                            $reviewer = $_POST['reviewer'];
                            $status = $_POST['status'];

                            $query = $conn->query($sql4);
                            if($query->num_rows > 0){
                            while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){


                                //...insert into your DB.
                                $row1 = $row["Date"];
                            $row2 = $row["Time"];
                            $row3 = $row["Alias"];
                            $row4 = $row["Machine_Name"];
                            $row5 = $row["Build_Name"];
                            $row6 = $row['Build_Version'];
                            $row7 = $row["WinDBG"];
                            $row8 = $row[".NET_Framework"];

                            $sql5 = "INSERT INTO history (`Date`, `Time`, `Alias`, `Machine_Name`, `Build_Name`, `Build_version`, `WinDBG`, `.NET_Framework`, `Status`, `Reviewed_By`) 
                            VALUES ('".$row1."','".$row2."','".$row3."','".$row4."','".$row5."','".$row6."','".$row7."','".$row8."','".$status."','".$reviewer."') ";
                            if ($conn->query($sql5) === TRUE) {
                            //echo "New record created successfully";
                            //echo nl2br("\n");
                            echo "";

                            } else {
                            echo "Error: " . $sql5 . "<br>" . $conn->error;
                            }



                        } 
                    }

                     include 'popupmessage.html';

                 ?>
```

Please help me...!! I want to store the status for each row.
Like
row1 | Ready
row2 | Not Ready
But now it given same for all row.

Comment: what debugging have you done?

side note* - you're open to sql injection

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send radio button value in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14747803/how-to-send-radio-button-value-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

In the OP all the radio buttons of each data row do have the same name. You need an identifier for each row. Placing a data row ID into the radio name would help. In PHP loop over each row to read the values of the radio buttons with the help of the data row ID.

Comment: any example please...!!

Comment: @KunalMajumder please try yourself first. I won't rewrite the code for you.